# onsavedinstancestate doesn't appear to support double array list what are my options?

Tags: android

`OnSavedInstanceState` in android doesn't appear to save double array list. I'm thinking the best way thing to do here is to convert the double array list to a double array, How do I go about doing that?

Is there a better option than convert double array list to double array.

```
/* Storage for parsed JSON data */
private List<String> mPosterPaths = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> mTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> mDescriptionList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Double> mRatingList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> mDateList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Integer> mIdList = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Double[] rating = mRatingList.toArray(new Double[0]);
    outState.putString("SavedState", mSortType);
    outState.putStringArrayList("PosterPath", (ArrayList<String>) mPosterPaths);
    outState.putStringArrayList("MovieTitle", (ArrayList<String>) mTitleList);
    outState.putIntegerArrayList("MovieID", (ArrayList<Integer>) mIdList);
    outState.putStringArrayList("Plot", (ArrayList<String>) mDescriptionList);
    outState.putDoubleArray("Rating",  mRatingList);
    outState.putStringArrayList("Release Date", (ArrayList<String>) mDateList);



}
```

Comment: Please post the code, and also please note that when you store data in bundle it should be parcelable or serilizable

Comment: I've include the my code hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to convert your ratings `List` to an `Array`:

```
double ratings[] = new double[mRatingList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < mRatingList.size(); i++) {
    ratings[i] = mRatingList.get(i);
}
savedInstanceState.putDoubleArray("Rating", ratings);
```

And when it is being restored:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    double[] ratings = savedInstanceState.getDoubleArray("Rating");
    List<Double> ratingList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (double rating : ratings) {
        ratingList.add(rating);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me unless I'm missing something. This is what the Log.d Prints back.

D/doubleconvert: arrayList[6.6, 5.6, 8.3, 7.6, 6.0, 8.3, 7.5, 6.2, 5.3, 7.3, 6.9, 7.0, 6.6, 6.9, 5.5, 6.5, 6.4, 4.1, 6.1, 6.9]

2018-11-12 21:07:49.064 23845-23845/com.shawn.nichol.moviesstage2 D/doubleconvert: array[D@81ead05

Comment: As you mentioned, Bundle doesn't support list of doubles. But it supports array of doubles, so you could try to convert the list to an array and put them in the Bundle, unless I misunderstood you?

Comment: @morefaster By the way its `double` not `Double` if that's what you mean, otherwise other options will be converting those to Serializable or Parcelable, or even String.

Comment: I just caught that two thinking that might the issue but I still get this response from the Log [D@a983e61.

Comment: Were you trying to print by `array.toString()`? That'd only give you a hash value. If you want to print readable strings, then try `Arrays.toString(array)`.

Comment: Hey that worked, that's exciting. Know When onRestoreInstanceState runs do I put this data into a double array and converted it to a double array list or can I put it in a double array list right away?

Comment: I wish there were a simpler way, but unfortunately you have to convert them to a `double` list.

Comment: Oh man, I feel like this course has dropped the ball on material that is required for their assignments. I'm very grateful for all the help Aaron.